# C: combine return & scanf() in one line

Tags: c, stdin, scanf

I'm writing a program in C that displays a menu that asks the user to make a decision.

I want to bring up the menu multiple times in the program so I put it into function.

Each choice has a number associated with it:

```
(1) Add
(2) Subtract
```

The function displays the menu and then then I `scanf` the `int` response to a local variable and then return the variable (I of course declare the variable at the beginning of the function).

```
int function ()
{
    int choice;

    // *insert print menu code here*

    scanf(" %i", &choice);

    return choice;
}
```

Can I make this shorter by somehow doing a: `return scanf(" %i", stdin);`

I'm not sure if `stdin` would be the right choice, but that's what searching tells me.

Comment: What do you honestly hope to achieve by making this change?

Comment: I was just curious if it was possible.  I just like knowing shortcuts, even if they aren't clean coding. I especially like the conditional operator shortcut even though it would be better to write out the if, else if.

But from what I'm seeing it looks like I'm just going to have to live with the extra code, like others have said

Comment: The best way to answer this question for yourself is to look at the documentation for the function `scanf()` and see what it is documented to return.  http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Comment: Why exactly are you using whitespace in `scanf` call? Be careful. Anyways, if you want your input to be the next digit character from `stdin` as an `int`, maybe you should do `getchar() - '0'`. See [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) on `getchar` as defined in `stdio.h`.

Comment: in a C programming book it said to avoid whitespace input you can use: scanf(" %i", &int); or scanf("% i", &int);

I've also seen adding a scant("%*i",null)  after or something like that

Comment: As @JimBalter says in a reply below, if you don't check the return value of scanf and return the value of an uninitialised variable, the behavior of your code is undefined. That means it could literally do anything if the user enters invalid input.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can:

```
int scanInt(void) {
  int result;
  return (scanf(" %i", &result), result);
}
```

But is it useful? Probably not.

---

Note that this *might* look like undefined behaviour at first glance, because you're writing and reading from the same memory location in one expression. But it is not, as the comma operator introduces a sequence point.

Comment: Who does this use of ',' look like undefined behavior to? ',' is even known as "the sequence operator". However, if scanf doesn't return 1, the value of result is undefined.

Comment: @JimBalter: Just added that note for clarity. On the first glimpse, if I see a line with a read and a write, UB pops into mind. Note that it **would be** UB, if the comma wasn't a comma operator, but a delimiter in a function call. However, I edited the wording.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with `scanf`: you'd be returning the *return value* of `scanf`, which only indicates the number of items successfully read. If you need to return `choice` then you'll need to call `scanf` to fill `choice` and return it in two separate steps.

Another point here is that you should check the return value of `scanf`: it will fail if it's unable to convert the input. In your code, `scanf` will fail if the input is not an integer.

Furthermore, `scanf` reads from `stdin` - standard input - by default, you can't pass that as an argument unless you're using `fscanf`, which otherwise behaves in the same way.

Have you looked at using `fgets` for your input? It *does* return the next input line, which *would* allow you to do the read in the `return` statement since `fgets` returns the next line of input as a string. But you'd still need to parse the input yourself, which should probably happen *within* your `function`. In any case, `fgets` is typically a better choice for user input because it separates reading the input from parsing it, and avoids problems when using `scanf` due to input that doesn't match your format string.

Comment: *Never* use `gets()`. You can use `fgets()` instead; it's a bit less convenient, but it's not prone to inavoidable buffer overruns.

Answer (score 1):

You can, sort of -- but don't.

`scanf` returns the number of items scanned. You can't make it return the value of one of the scanned items.

```
return scanf(" %i", &choice), choice;
```

This uses the comma operator (not to be confused with the comma delimiter between function arguments), which evaluates both operands and yields the result of the right operand.

But there is no good reason to do this. There is no great virtue in making your source code more compact like this. The multi-line form is clearer, and it's easier to modify by adding error handling (what happens if the user enters something other than a number?)

Or you could write your own function that calls `scanf` and returns the value you want, but that still doesn't address the issue of error handling.

And if your goal is simply to put them on one line:

```
scanf(" %i", &choice); return choice;
```

But again, this is not an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't with `scanf`. The function needs a memory location to store the result, and doesn't return it. So you just have to live with the extra code.